# Application hangs up when copying files to USB

Tags: windows-vista, usb, freeze

When I copy files from my notebook to USB device (both player and smartphone), application hangs up. I try to perform copying both in Windows Explorer and Far Manager for this. 
After this Far manager could not be closed even when I try to switch off notebook.

When I perform copying in save mode - all are ok.
When I perform copying to usual USB flash memory - all are ok.

With what could the issue be connected?

I use Windows Vista 32.
I also tried to stop all services which are possible - the same behavior.

Notebook model is ASUS_F7Se.

Comment: Have you tried all USB ports on your notebook? Have to connected the player/smartphone to someone else's PC? What are the USB-specs of your player/smartphone?